# Stock issue - Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3, stock

We have an issue, not anything major, more like an annoying issue, and we do not understand why.

One of our stores has low stock, so if we have 1 left and someone buys it, in Magento admin, it shows up as "out of stock" but says that we have 1 left, which causes issues when we do products count, etc.

If we have 2 left in stock and someone buys, then there is no issue. It lowers the stock to 1. It is only when the stock goes from 1 to 0 that it won't update.

Does anyone have the same "issue"? It isn't very pleasant when we do stock counting when we think we have something in stock.

[image: Stock settings]

Any help is appreciated

**List of disabled modules:**

```
Magento_Inventory
Magento_InventoryAdminUi
Magento_InventoryAdvancedCheckout
Magento_InventoryApi
Magento_InventoryBundleProduct
Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalog
Magento_InventorySales
Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi
Magento_InventoryCatalogApi
Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryConfiguration
Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi
Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryElasticsearch
Magento_InventoryExportStockApi
Magento_InventoryIndexer
Magento_InventorySalesApi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer
Magento_InventoryImportExport
Magento_InventoryCache
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi
Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi
Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi
Magento_InventoryProductAlert
Magento_InventoryRequisitionList
Magento_InventoryReservations
Magento_InventoryReservationCli
Magento_InventoryReservationsApi
Magento_InventoryExportStock
Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi
Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi
Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator
Magento_InventoryShipping
Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi
Magento_InventorySourceSelection
Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi
Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi
Magento_InventoryGraphQl
Amasty_Feed
KraftMedia_CustomStoreSwitcher
Litespeed_Litemage
Mageplaza_LayeredNavigation
Wyomind_ElasticsearchCore
Wyomind_ElasticsearchAutocomplete
```

Comment: is Magento Multi Stock Inventory enabled? can you also attach a screenshot of your products grid with only the product with the issue in there?

Comment: Hi, 

I can't find where the Multi Stock Inventory option is. 
I have also attached a picture above of our stock setting. Please let me know if you need more info. 

I do not have any picture of the products now as we have manually fixed the stock.

Comment: i see. ok. well the idea is that if you have the MSI modules enabled, your products have 2 types of qty (quantity and saleable quantity). i'm assuming you see the qty=1, whereas saleable qty=0 (you normally see these values in the product grid in admin. what happens is that as orders get placed, the salable qty is decreased, whereas the quantity field remains the same UNTIL you ship the order (create order shipment). i'm assuming this is the problem you have.

Comment: when you run `bin/magento module:status` does it show a list of inventory related modules?

Comment: I have added the result, cheers

Comment: mea culpa :) i wanted to ask what you see after the 'List of disabled modules:' line in the results of the command execution.

Comment: Do you need to see what modules I have disabled? I do not have anything under disabled modules

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120405/discussion-between-diana-botean-and-jan-petter-havna).